# Phaser JS - Button cannot set frame name from image sprite

Tags: javascript, phaser-framework

As part of my practice with phaser, I'm trying to create a basic clicker game. However, I can not get the button to display the image I wanted.

Here's my main **gameplay.js**:

```
class Gameplay extends Phaser.State {

init()
{
  var btnUp = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'btn_beerUp');
  var btnDn = this.game.add.sprite(0, 0, 'btn_beerDn');
  this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX - 100, this.game.world.centerY + 230, 'game', this.pauseGame, this, btnUp.key, btnUp.key, btnDn.key);
  this.clickButton.anchor.set(0.5, 0.5);
}
```

And here's my **preloader.js** (where ideally, all images are loaded):

```
class Preload extends Phaser.State {
  create() {
      this.game.load.image('btn_beerDn', 'res/img/btn_beerClickerDn.png');
      this.game.load.image('btn_beerUp', 'res/img/btn_beerClickerUp.png');
  }
```

It doesn't work as expected. The game simply adds the `btnUp` and `btnDn` as images in the scene, and does nothing for the button.

I've also tried the following:

```
this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(blah-blah, 'btn_beerUp', 'btn_beerUp', 'btn_beerDn');

this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(blah-blah, 'res/img/btn_beerClickerUp.png', 'res/img/btn_beerClickerUp.png', 'res/img/btn_beerClickerDn.png');
```

But none of them work - the button still displays a button with an "x".

The samples online mostly deal with atlas sheets from what I can look up. While I will eventually progress to using an atlas sheet for buttons, it seems silly that I can't get simply using a png working.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Per [the documentation](http://phaser.io/docs/2.6.2/Phaser.Button.html#frame), if you're not going to pass in a frame or frame name you'll have to use `loadTexture` instead.

If you look at the [Action On Click](https://phaser.io/examples/v2/buttons/action-on-click) example you'll see how you add actions for each of the button states.

In your case you'll want to change this line:

```
this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX - 100, this.game.world.centerY + 230, 'game'
    , this.pauseGame, this, btnUp.key, btnUp.key, btnDn.key);
```

To something like the following:

```
this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX - 100, this.game.world.centerY + 230, 'game'
    , this.pauseGame, this);
this.clickButton.onInputOut.add(this.out, this);
// TODO add your other input events.

out: function () {
    this.clickButton.loadTexture(btnUp.key);
}
// TODO add functions for your other input events.
```

Full working example:

```js
var mainState = {
    preload: function() {
     // Load the three sprites that they can choose between.
      this.load.crossOrigin = 'anonymous';
      this.load.image('ball', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/master/examples/assets/sprites/orb-blue.png');
      this.load.image('ball2', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/master/examples/assets/sprites/orb-green.png');
      this.load.image('ball3', 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/photonstorm/phaser-examples/master/examples/assets/sprites/orb-red.png');
    },

    create: function() {
      // This won't work, since the passed items aren't valid frameNames.
      //this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'ball', this.buttonClick, this, 'ball2', 'ball', 'ball3', 'ball');
      // This follows what the documentation states, if you're not using a spritesheet.
      this.clickButton = this.game.add.button(this.game.world.centerX, this.game.world.centerY, 'ball', this.buttonClick, this);
      
      this.clickButton.onInputOver.add(this.buttonOver, this);
      this.clickButton.onInputOut.add(this.buttonOut, this);
      this.clickButton.onInputDown.add(this.buttonDown, this);
      this.clickButton.onInputUp.add(this.buttonUp, this);

   this.clickButton.anchor.setTo(0.5);
    },
    update: function() {
    },
    buttonClick: function() {
      alert('clicked');
   },
    buttonOver: function() {
      this.clickButton.loadTexture('ball2');
    },
    buttonOut: function() {
      this.clickButton.loadTexture('ball');
    },
    buttonDown: function() {
      this.clickButton.loadTexture('ball3');
    },
    buttonUp: function() {
      this.clickButton.loadTexture('ball');
    }
};

var game = new Phaser.Game(200, 200);

game.state.add('main', mainState);

game.state.start('main');
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/phaser-ce@2.7.10"></script>
```

Also saved as [a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/strivinglife/oaepqdqo/).